# What happens if a vehicle is reported sold and never registered again?

Tags: united-states, vehicle, nevada

I understand  the registration  is suspended after x days if the buyer fails to register. But what if they never register, does the registration never get un suspended?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here.  If nobody ever registers it, then the vehicle won't ever have a valid registration.  Typically this means it can't legally be driven or parked on public streets.

Comment: You've told the Nevada DMV that you sold the car, right? Then they'll  end your registration. A buyer could take the car out of state--it would never be registered in NV under the new owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's not registered

I'm pretty sure this car is not registered.

[image]

It's not a requirement to register motor vehicles. It is illegal to drive an unregistered vehicle on public roads.

Comment: Seller is basically screwed if they want it back?

Comment: Where does that result come from? The car still exists, presumably if they want it enough to buy it back, it's either in condition to be registered or they will expend the effort to make it so. Being registered, being owned, being in any particular condition are all separate things, only some of which rely on others. @user30672

Comment: @Nij I’m wondering if there is something administrative in the OP’s jurisdiction that means they are still responsible for the car until the buyer dies something

Comment: But if the buyer does literally  nothing aren't they stuck?

Comment: @user30672 that's true of anything you might sell.  If you sell something and want it back, you have to convince the buyer to sell it back to you.  That is the same for a saxophone, a necklace, or a car.  In the last case, whether the buyer has registered the car in the meanwhile has no bearing on this.